# ASP.NET MVC Html Helpers - is Response.Write needed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

When using the Html helpers for ASP.NET MVC I need to wrap them in a Response.Write else they don't appear. However the samples ([1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410596.aspx)&[2](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/asp_net_mvc_imagelink.aspx) for example) I find online for ASP.NET MVC don't seem to do that. Did something change somewhere or am I doing something wrong?

From the samples I find it should be like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <% Html.ActionLink("View", "Details", "People"); %>
</div>
```

However that displays nothing, so I need to wrap it in a Response.Write as follows:

```
<div class="row">
  <% Response.Write(Html.ActionLink("View", "Details", "People")); %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to write them like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <%= Html.ActionLink("View", "Details", "People") %>
</div>
```

Note the <%= before the Html.ActionLink. This writes the value into the response.

Comment: You can use `<%:` in later versions

Answer (score 9):

`Html.ActionLink` does not write anything to the response stream. It just returns a `string`. To output that in the response you need to use `Response.Write`:

```
<% Response.Write(Html.ActionLink("View", "Details", "People")); %>
```

or alternatively, there's a shorthand for `Response.Write`:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("View", "Details", "People") %>
```

Note that the latter syntax requires an *expression* rather than a statement, thus it shouldn't have semicolon.